# Are usb pendrives/sticks random access?

Tags: performance, usb-storage

Do USB pendrives/sticks have random access (i.e. accessing one block will take equal amount of time, regardless of the previous block read) characteristic?

Comment: Do you want to know if the access is random, or are you just wondering about performance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the access is not truly random since USB flash drives use NAND flash, according to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random-access_memory):

> With flash memory, only the NOR type is capable of true random access, allowing direct code execution, and is therefore often used instead of ROM; the lower cost NAND type is commonly used for bulk storage in memory cards and solid-state drives.

[And](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_memory#NAND_flash):

> NAND flash memory forms the core of the removable USB storage devices known as USB flash drives, as well as most memory card formats and solid-state drives available today.

Answer (score 3):

Reads should all take the same time. Writes are another matter; flash is split into fairly large blocks, and you have to erase all of a block before it can be written to.